# Illustrator: How to add background to images with slight extra border

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, outline

[image: Example Image]

For the example image above - I would like to add a white background. However, I want that white background to "trace" around the logo + text so it isn't simply a rectangle.

I'll try to explain another way: Think of this image with a white stroke added to the outside of the shapes + letters. That cares for the shapes specifically, but I will have transparency in-between the shapes and in-between the larger gaps of the stroke.

Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve, except I want the INSIDE of the white outline filled also.

I hope this makes sense.

[image: Image Example]

Answer (score 2):

One method is simply to group the objects, then add a very thick stroke to the group via the **Appearance Panel**. Lastly, move the stroke below the `Contents` on the panel....

[image]

You could expand this artwork via `Object > Expand Appearance`, then `Object > Expand` and `Object > Expand` (I had to expand twice because the group contained live type. If there's no live type, one expand should work.)

[image]

Then tap the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**...

[image]

---

Another option is to add a new **Fill** via the **Appearance Panel**. Move the fill below the `Contents` on the panel and highlight it. Then choose `Effect > Path > Offset Path` from the menu. Adjust to your liking...

[image]

Then you can follow the same expand steps above to get actual shapes you can manipulate if desired.

---

The difference between using a fill vs a stoke is in the *Stroke Options*. With strokes you can do things like tick the `Round Corners` option to, well, round stroke corners easily if desired.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. This doesn't work for my need, though, because my graphic has a picture (on the left where the Li is in the example) with larger gaps. So I would have to increase the stoke so greatly, the border becomes huge around everything else. Are there any other methods that may work?